# Casual way to say: ''See you tomorrow at (some time)''

Tags: time

Lets say 11am

How would you say: ''See you tomorrow at 11.'' ?

All I have is :

ashita wa juuichi ji ni ... what now ? ...

I found this expression online :

11 のあなたは見てください

Comment: "I found this expression online" where? If you don't mind me asking

Comment: I know Google Translate is not always a recommended resource for translation, but copy-pasting "See you tomorrow at 11" gives 「また明日11時に会いましょう」, which seems pretty accurate to me (at least compared to 「11 のあなたは見てください」).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Roughly in the order of informality, native speakers would say:

・「じゃあ、明日{あした}（の）[１１時]{じゅういちじ}**に**！」 (no verb)

・「では、明日（の）１１時に！」

・「それでは、明日（の）１１時に！」

・「じゃあ/では/それでは、明日（の）１１時に（また）会{あ}いましょう。」 (with verb)

The last phrase above is already "borderline formal", but for many adult speakers (if not for teenagers), it would sound fairly informal.  An example of the formal phrase by anyone's standard would be:

・「では/それでは、明日{あす}の１１時に（また）**お**会い**いたしましょう**。」

Notice that I dropped the 「じゃあ」 option as it is too informal to go with this level of formality.  Notice also that 「明日」 is read 「あす」 here to fit better in the formal phrase.

> I found this expression online :
>
> 11 のあなたは見てください

That is just ***complete*** gibberish, period.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that that sentence is gibberish. It made me wince, haha.

Answer (score 1):

A neat way I always used to say it was to roll together "tomorrow" with either "morning" / "afternoon" / "evening".
A native would probably never say it in conversation but would always understand. The following are more written / formal words (I think?):
みょうちょう = "tomorrow morning" (shorthand for 明日の朝)
みょうばん = "tomorrow evening" (shorthand for 明日の夜)

So, saying "みょうちょう、９時に会うぞ" is sort of a succinct, informal, way to say "See you at 9-am tomorrow morning". See how you are shrinking "tomorrow morning" into just 2 sounds "みょう and ちょう". A native speaker would "think twice" (and hopefully think its a little clever.)